# nodejs - Statements after await Promise without resolve are skipped

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

Running the following snippet, `console.log('done.')` is skipped:

```
function test (cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('2000ms passed')
    cb && cb()
  }, 2000)
}

async function run () {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Doesn't run console.log('done') with test():
    // But if test(resolve), console.log('done.') will run
    test() 
  })
  console.log('done.')
}

run()
```

Why `test()` without `resolve` doesn't run `console.log('done.')` ?

Comment: Because your promise stuck in pending state forever. `await promise` would stop function execution util the promise got resolved or rejected. There is no timeout out of the box. Since you neither call `resolve` nor `reject` the outer function will never continue its execution.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko But the snippet finishes after 2 seconds without stuck. Why won't the program just hang there forever ?

Comment: The thing is pending promise does not create a task. So there is nothing left to do in event loop. So node just exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise becomes resolved only when you call the `resolve` callback. If promise was not resolved or rejected it remains in the `pending` state forever.

`Await` keyword is used to actually "wait until promise resolves" and it never happens in your example.

Your function `test` expects some function to execute when timeout passes. When you pass `resolve` as an argument of the `test` function it will be called after timeout, promise become resolved and you see the console logs.

I am not sure what is the result you are trying to achieve, but here is a short code snippet showing the implementation of 2 seconds `sleep` function:

```js
function sleepTwoSeconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
}

async function run() {
  console.log('start');
  await sleepTwoSeconds();
  console.log('2 seconds passed');
}

run()
```

Comment: But the snippet finishes after 2 seconds without stuck. Why won't the program just hang there forever ?

Comment: Because there is actually no dangling callbacks in the process.